# Bitmap is null when tried to fetch image from frame affective

Tags: android, affdex-sdk

I have integrated affectiva library and trying to fetch emotions using camera stream.
I tried to fetch the bitmap from the frame returned but it always returns null.Below is the code.

```
  byte[] imageBytes = ((Frame.ByteArrayFrame) frame).getByteArray();
```

We have some 518 kb of data but when converted to image it returns null.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
    previewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

I even tried the below code but again null bitmap

```
Bitmap bmp=frame.getOriginalBitmapFrame();
```

Could you please help me to fetch bitmap from the frame?

Comment: Can you provide some context?  Where did the `frame` object come from?

Comment: The frame object is taken from onImageResults callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some sample conversion methods in Affectiva's `affdexme-android` sample app:

https://github.com/Affectiva/affdexme-android/blob/a0c732fb0378b9c0883d30fa21eaa9cf22b57eed/app/src/main/java/com/affectiva/affdexme/ImageHelper.java#L221

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromFrame(@NonNull final Frame frame) {
    Bitmap bitmap;

    if (frame instanceof Frame.BitmapFrame) {
        bitmap = ((Frame.BitmapFrame) frame).getBitmap();
    } else { //frame is ByteArrayFrame
        switch (frame.getColorFormat()) {
            case RGBA:
                bitmap = getBitmapFromRGBFrame(frame);
                break;
            case YUV_NV21:
                bitmap = getBitmapFromYuvFrame(frame);
                break;
            case UNKNOWN_TYPE:
            default:
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unable to get bitmap from unknown frame type");
                return null;
        }
    }

    if (bitmap == null || frame.getTargetRotation().toDouble() == 0.0) {
        return bitmap;
    } else {
        return rotateBitmap(bitmap, (float) frame.getTargetRotation().toDouble());
    }
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromRGBFrame(@NonNull final Frame frame) {
    byte[] pixels = ((Frame.ByteArrayFrame) frame).getByteArray();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(pixels));
    return bitmap;
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromYuvFrame(@NonNull final Frame frame) {
    byte[] pixels = ((Frame.ByteArrayFrame) frame).getByteArray();
    YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(pixels, ImageFormat.NV21, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), null);
    return convertYuvImageToBitmap(yuvImage);
}

/**
 * Note: This conversion procedure is sloppy and may result in JPEG compression artifacts
 *
 * @param yuvImage - The YuvImage to convert
 * @return - The converted Bitmap
 */
public static Bitmap convertYuvImageToBitmap(@NonNull final YuvImage yuvImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, yuvImage.getWidth(), yuvImage.getHeight()), 100, out);
    byte[] imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception while closing output stream", e);
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
}

public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(@NonNull final Bitmap source, final float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```